# A new rebus that needs reflection

Tags: rebus

Here's a new rebus, hope you like it :)

> [image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The notes are AB. Adding a mirror image to this produces ABBA. There is the [logo](https://goodlogo.com/extended.info/queen-logo-3009) of the band Queen on top of the mirror and the figures inside are dancing. Maybe the answer is **dancing queen**, which is a song by ABBA?

Comment: Yep! Well done :)

Answer (score 6):

This is probably WAY off, but here you go anyways:

> The notes are ab. ab backwards(reflection) is ba. ba + dance = badance = bad + ants? bad ants?

Comment: nice try but that's not correct :p